# Django: localize the API calls's resposnse

Tags: python, django

I have API interface for my application and  want the response of these calls to support various languages.

```
def get_student(request):
 //code
 return JsonResponse(content={"Message": "student is found"}, status=200)
```

I have gone through [django-localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/) documentation and have created a **po and mo** files for specific language. 
And now i'm stuck on how to use those files and give the response in particular language.

any help or reference will be appreciated. 

**EDIT: this one helped**
settings.LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'locale')) 
and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/i18n/

Comment: You're linking to a rather old version of the doc (1.3.x)...

Comment: working with legacy code for project, unfortunately no choice

Comment: well, bad luck. But this part didn't change much anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Before you worrying about .mo and .po files, you need to set up the various flags, languages and middlewares in your settings, and mark translatable text in your apps and templates.

You should start here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/ for the big pictures and definitions, then continue here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/translation/ for how to mark the translatable strings. Don't skip the notes as there are some configuration job to do.

About how to mark as string as translatable, in your above snippet, it should looks like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def get_student(request):
   //code
   return JsonResponse(content={"Message": _(u"student is found")}, status=200)
```

Once you're done with marking all your translatable texts, it's time to generate the source translation files (.po), edit them with the actual translations and finally generate the compiled translations files (.mo) as documented.